# nHibernate trying to update instead of insert a new object

Tags: nhibernate, attributes

I am using nHibernate attributes which generates this...

```
  <class name="xxx.Message.MtMessage, xxx" lazy="false" table="tblCore_MtMessage">
    <id name="MtMessageId">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="MtMessageStatus" />
    <property name="ApplicationMessageId" />
    <property name="IsPremium" />
    <property name="Tariff" />
    <property name="ExpiryTimeMinutes" />
    <property name="PhoneNetwork" />
    <property name="MessageText" />
    <property name="ToNumber" />
    <property name="FromNumber" />
    <property name="IsCompleted" />
    <property name="UpdateDate" />
    <many-to-one name="Category" class="xxx.Category, xxx" column="CategoryId" not-null="true" cascade="None" />
    <many-to-one name="Aggregator" class="xxx.AbstractAggregator, xxx" column="AggregatorId" cascade="None" />
    <many-to-one name="Aggregator" class="xxx.AbstractAggregator, xxx" column="AggregatorId" cascade="None" />
    <many-to-one name="Application" class="xxx.Application, xxx" column="ApplicationId" cascade="None" />
    <many-to-one name="Application" class="xxx.Application, xxx" column="ApplicationId" cascade="None" />
    <bag name="Segments" lazy="false" inverse="true" cascade="None">
      <key column="MtMessageId" />
      <one-to-many class="xxx.Message.MtSegment, xxx" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="xxx.Message.MoMessage, xxx" lazy="false" table="tblCore_MoMessage">
    <id name="MoMessageId">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="MoMessageStatus" />
    <property name="PhoneNetwork" />
    <property name="MessageText" />
    <property name="ToNumber" />
    <property name="FromNumber" />
    <property name="IsCompleted" />
    <property name="UpdateDate" />
    <list name="Segments" lazy="false" inverse="true" cascade="None">
      <key column="MoMessageId" />
      <index column="SegmentNumber" />
      <one-to-many class="xxx.Message.MoSegment, xxx" />
    </list>
  </class>
```

For some reason, when I create a new MoMessage and call ISession.Save() on it nHibernate tries to UPDATE instead of INSERT.  I have no problem saving the MtMessage.  I have tried changing the list for a bag as thats the only real difference, that didn't work.  Anyone got any pointers where to start looking???

Here's a big of logging that may help

```
2010-09-09 18:53:54,015 DEBUG xxx.NHibernate.ReceiveMoUow - Saving message[Id:0,Type:MO,To:89000,From:447000000000,Network:O2,Status:New,Text:Hi mum]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG xxx.Persist.NHibernateConnection - CreateSession(Commit)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=408ca207-0ed1-487f-b57b-ae6a072a4d3f] opened session at timestamp: 634196552340, for session factory: [/0754517161044239b072f9d048fcb17f]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - put criteria=PhoneNumber = 447000000000 and IsEnabled = True alias=this0_
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - returning alias=this_ for criteria=PhoneNumber = 447000000000 and IsEnabled = True
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - returning alias=this_ for criteria=PhoneNumber = 447000000000 and IsEnabled = True
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - getCriteria for path=Application crit=
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - getCriteria for path=Application.RedirectApplication crit=
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 12 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 16 for the table dbo.tblCore_PhoneDiverts this_
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened new IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Building an IDbCommand object for the SqlString: SELECT this_.PhoneNumber as PhoneNum1_9_2_, this_.DivertName as DivertName9_2_, this_.IsEnabled as IsEnabled9_2_, this_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate9_2_, this_.ApplicationId as Applicat5_9_2_, applicatio2_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_0_, applicatio2_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_0_, applicatio2_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_0_, applicatio2_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_0_, applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_0_, applicatio3_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_1_, applicatio3_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_1_, applicatio3_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_1_, applicatio3_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_1_, applicatio3_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_1_ FROM dbo.tblCore_PhoneDiverts this_ left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio2_ on this_.ApplicationId=applicatio2_.ApplicationId left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio3_ on applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId=applicatio3_.ApplicationId WHERE this_.PhoneNumber = ? and this_.IsEnabled = ?
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.QueryParameters - BindParameters(Named:NHibernate.Type.StringType) 447000000000 -> [0]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.StringType - binding '447000000000' to parameter: 0
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.QueryParameters - BindParameters(Named:NHibernate.Type.BooleanType) True -> [1]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.BooleanType - binding 'True' to parameter: 1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 INFO  NHibernate.Loader.Loader - SELECT this_.PhoneNumber as PhoneNum1_9_2_, this_.DivertName as DivertName9_2_, this_.IsEnabled as IsEnabled9_2_, this_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate9_2_, this_.ApplicationId as Applicat5_9_2_, applicatio2_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_0_, applicatio2_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_0_, applicatio2_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_0_, applicatio2_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_0_, applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_0_, applicatio3_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_1_, applicatio3_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_1_, applicatio3_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_1_, applicatio3_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_1_, applicatio3_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_1_ FROM dbo.tblCore_PhoneDiverts this_ left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio2_ on this_.ApplicationId=applicatio2_.ApplicationId left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio3_ on applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId=applicatio3_.ApplicationId WHERE this_.PhoneNumber = @p0 and this_.IsEnabled = @p1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - SELECT this_.PhoneNumber as PhoneNum1_9_2_, this_.DivertName as DivertName9_2_, this_.IsEnabled as IsEnabled9_2_, this_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate9_2_, this_.ApplicationId as Applicat5_9_2_, applicatio2_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_0_, applicatio2_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_0_, applicatio2_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_0_, applicatio2_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_0_, applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_0_, applicatio3_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_1_, applicatio3_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_1_, applicatio3_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_1_, applicatio3_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_1_, applicatio3_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_1_ FROM dbo.tblCore_PhoneDiverts this_ left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio2_ on this_.ApplicationId=applicatio2_.ApplicationId left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio3_ on applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId=applicatio3_.ApplicationId WHERE this_.PhoneNumber = @p0 and this_.IsEnabled = @p1;@p0 = '447000000000', @p1 = True
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider - Obtaining IDbConnection from Driver
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - ExecuteReader took 1 ms
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened IDataReader, open IDataReaders: 1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - processing result set
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - done processing result set (0 rows)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader - running NHybridDataReader.Dispose()
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDataReader, open IDataReaders :0
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - DataReader was closed after 1 ms
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 0
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing database connection
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider - Closing connection
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - total objects hydrated: 0
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - after autocommit
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - transaction completion
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing database connection
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=408ca207-0ed1-487f-b57b-ae6a072a4d3f] running ISession.Dispose()
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=408ca207-0ed1-487f-b57b-ae6a072a4d3f] executing real Dispose(True)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - closing session
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - running BatcherImpl.Dispose(true)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG xxx.Persist.NHibernateConnection - CreateSession(Commit)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=fce26533-bf6c-4f93-b75e-61a8c88c1e87] opened session at timestamp: 634196552340, for session factory: [/0754517161044239b072f9d048fcb17f]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - put criteria=PhoneNetwork = O2 and IsEnabled = True alias=this0_
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - returning alias=this_ for criteria=PhoneNetwork = O2 and IsEnabled = True
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - returning alias=this_ for criteria=PhoneNetwork = O2 and IsEnabled = True
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - getCriteria for path=Application crit=
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - getCriteria for path=Application.RedirectApplication crit=
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 12 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 16 for the table dbo.tblCore_NetworkDiverts this_
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened new IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Building an IDbCommand object for the SqlString: SELECT this_.PhoneNetwork as PhoneNet1_13_2_, this_.IsEnabled as IsEnabled13_2_, this_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate13_2_, this_.ApplicationId as Applicat4_13_2_, applicatio2_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_0_, applicatio2_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_0_, applicatio2_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_0_, applicatio2_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_0_, applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_0_, applicatio3_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_1_, applicatio3_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_1_, applicatio3_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_1_, applicatio3_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_1_, applicatio3_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_1_ FROM dbo.tblCore_NetworkDiverts this_ left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio2_ on this_.ApplicationId=applicatio2_.ApplicationId left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio3_ on applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId=applicatio3_.ApplicationId WHERE this_.PhoneNetwork = ? and this_.IsEnabled = ?
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.QueryParameters - BindParameters(Named:NHibernate.Type.PersistentEnumType) O2 -> [0]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.PersistentEnumType - binding '0' to parameter: 0
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.QueryParameters - BindParameters(Named:NHibernate.Type.BooleanType) True -> [1]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.BooleanType - binding 'True' to parameter: 1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 INFO  NHibernate.Loader.Loader - SELECT this_.PhoneNetwork as PhoneNet1_13_2_, this_.IsEnabled as IsEnabled13_2_, this_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate13_2_, this_.ApplicationId as Applicat4_13_2_, applicatio2_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_0_, applicatio2_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_0_, applicatio2_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_0_, applicatio2_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_0_, applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_0_, applicatio3_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_1_, applicatio3_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_1_, applicatio3_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_1_, applicatio3_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_1_, applicatio3_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_1_ FROM dbo.tblCore_NetworkDiverts this_ left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio2_ on this_.ApplicationId=applicatio2_.ApplicationId left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio3_ on applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId=applicatio3_.ApplicationId WHERE this_.PhoneNetwork = @p0 and this_.IsEnabled = @p1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - SELECT this_.PhoneNetwork as PhoneNet1_13_2_, this_.IsEnabled as IsEnabled13_2_, this_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate13_2_, this_.ApplicationId as Applicat4_13_2_, applicatio2_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_0_, applicatio2_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_0_, applicatio2_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_0_, applicatio2_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_0_, applicatio2_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_0_, applicatio2_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_0_, applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_0_, applicatio3_.ApplicationId as Applicat1_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationName as Applicat2_3_1_, applicatio3_.ValidationKey as Validati3_3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceUrl as Applicat4_3_1_, applicatio3_.IpAddress as IpAddress3_1_, applicatio3_.ApplicationWebInterfaceVersion as Applicat6_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldSend as ShouldSend3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldRedirect as ShouldRe8_3_1_, applicatio3_.ShouldDumpMessage as ShouldDu9_3_1_, applicatio3_.UpdateDate as UpdateDate3_1_, applicatio3_.RedirectApplicationId as Redirec11_3_1_ FROM dbo.tblCore_NetworkDiverts this_ left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio2_ on this_.ApplicationId=applicatio2_.ApplicationId left outer join dbo.tblCore_Applications applicatio3_ on applicatio2_.RedirectApplicationId=applicatio3_.ApplicationId WHERE this_.PhoneNetwork = @p0 and this_.IsEnabled = @p1;@p0 = 0, @p1 = True
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider - Obtaining IDbConnection from Driver
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - ExecuteReader took 0 ms
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened IDataReader, open IDataReaders: 1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - processing result set
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - done processing result set (0 rows)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader - running NHybridDataReader.Dispose()
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDataReader, open IDataReaders :0
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - DataReader was closed after 1 ms
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 0
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing database connection
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider - Closing connection
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - total objects hydrated: 0
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - after autocommit
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - transaction completion
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing database connection
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=fce26533-bf6c-4f93-b75e-61a8c88c1e87] running ISession.Dispose()
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=fce26533-bf6c-4f93-b75e-61a8c88c1e87] executing real Dispose(True)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - closing session
2010-09-09 18:53:54,031 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - running BatcherImpl.Dispose(true)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,046 DEBUG xxx.Persist.NHibernateConnection - CreateSession(Commit)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,046 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=d70b7e2f-062a-4495-83d0-380345acf920] opened session at timestamp: 634196552340, for session factory: [/0754517161044239b072f9d048fcb17f]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,046 DEBUG NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction - Begin (Unspecified)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,046 DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider - Obtaining IDbConnection from Driver
2010-09-09 18:53:54,062 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener - updating detached instance
2010-09-09 18:53:54,078 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener - updating [xxx.Message.MoMessage#0]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,093 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - collection dereferenced while transient [xxx.Message.MoMessage.Segments#0]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,093 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener - updating [xxx.Message.MoMessage#0]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,109 DEBUG NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction - Start Commit
2010-09-09 18:53:54,109 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - flushing session
2010-09-09 18:53:54,140 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - processing flush-time cascades
2010-09-09 18:53:54,140 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - dirty checking collections
2010-09-09 18:53:54,140 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
2010-09-09 18:53:54,171 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.WrapVisitor - Wrapped collection in role: xxx.Message.MoMessage.Segments
2010-09-09 18:53:54,171 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener - Updating entity: [xxx.Message.MoMessage#0]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,187 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.Collections - Collection found: [xxx.Message.MoMessage.Segments#0], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
2010-09-09 18:53:54,187 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing unreferenced collections
2010-09-09 18:53:54,187 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
2010-09-09 18:53:54,187 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2010-09-09 18:53:54,187 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 1 removals to 1 collections
2010-09-09 18:53:54,203 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.Printer - listing entities:
2010-09-09 18:53:54,203 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.Printer - xxx.Message.MoMessage{'MoMessageId'='0', 'MoMessageStatus'='52', 'PhoneNetwork'='0', 'MessageText'='Hi mum', 'ToNumber'='89000', 'FromNumber'='447000000000', 'IsCompleted'='True', 'UpdateDate'='09/09/2010 17:53:54', 'Aggregator'='xxx.AbstractAggregator#2', 'Application'='null', 'Segments'='['xxx.Message.MoSegment']'}
2010-09-09 18:53:54,203 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - executing flush
2010-09-09 18:53:54,203 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - registering flush begin
2010-09-09 18:53:54,218 DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Updating entity: [xxx.Message.MoMessage#0]
2010-09-09 18:53:54,218 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened new IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 1
2010-09-09 18:53:54,218 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Building an IDbCommand object for the SqlString: UPDATE dbo.tblCore_MoMessage SET MoMessageStatus = ?, PhoneNetwork = ?, MessageText = ?, ToNumber = ?, FromNumber = ?, IsCompleted = ?, UpdateDate = ?, AggregatorId = ?, ApplicationId = ? WHERE MoMessageId = ?
```

Comment: You've written "INSERT instead of UPDATE" the wrong way rounf in the question text, which is a little confusing. I'd also recommend cutting down the amount of fields in the mapping until you get to the simplest mapping that will still have the problem, this will make your question easier to answer.

Comment: Oops! Thanks, I've swapped them around now. Todays task is to start commenting stuff out till it works.  Thing is, MtMessage is way more complex than MoMessage and saves no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be opening another session inside my current one.  The second/inner session just loads some Aggregator and Application objects.  No idea why that is causing my problem all I can say is not opening another session and loading the other objects has solved the initial problem.

Looks like I will have to use the outer session to load the other objects but I have other stuff to do for now.